# Python Inserting Into 2D Array :list index out of range

Tags: python

In the following python code I am trying to create a 2D array, delete an element, and insert a new one in that same specified position. I am able to delete an element with a specified position, however when trying to insert I am getting the error: `IndexError: list index out of range`.
Thanks for any help

```
tda = []
for i in range(0,100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        col = []
        tda.append(col)
    col.append(random.randint(0,10))

del tda[1][1]
tda.insert([1][1],5)
```

Comment: **insert()** takes as an argument, the position you want to insert. You are passing a 2D position in the incorrect way. Maybe you wan to do **tda[1].insert(1,5)**?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're passing `[1][1]` as a list index. List indexes must be integers. For example, you could do:

```
tda[1].insert([5,23,32,53,43])
```

To insert an entire new "row" into your 2D array. Instead of deleting and inserting however, you should just index into the location you want to change and update it directly:

```
tda[1][1] = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
tda.insert ([1] [1], 5)
```

with

```
col = tda [1]
col.insert (1, 5)
```